# openFileDialog и string

Tags: c++, winapi, строки

```
std::string tool_system::System::openFileDialog(std::string filter)
{
    char FileName[260] = { 0 };
    char FilePath[260] = { 0 };

    OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.lpstrFile = FilePath;
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(FilePath);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = filter.c_str();
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = FileName;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_EXPLORER;

    if (!GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn))
        return "";

    return ofn.lpstrFile;
}
```

Почему нельзя подставлять в параметр "lpstrFilter"- string? Результат такой, как буд-то бы в параметр этот попадает мусор, но я пробовал очистить память - не помогает! А так отлично работает:

```
std::string tool_system::System::openFileDialog(const char* filter)
{
    char FileName[260] = { 0 };
    char FilePath[260] = { 0 };

    OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.lpstrFile = FilePath;
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(FilePath);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = filter;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = FileName;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_EXPLORER;

    if (!GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn))
        return "";

    return ofn.lpstrFile;
}
```

Почему нельзя использовать строку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорей всего Вы не правильно инициализируете строку.
Если `openFileDialog` принимает `std::string`, то его нельзя вызвать как

```
 openFileDialog("All Files\0*.*\0\0")
```

Т.к. фильтр должен содержать символы `\0`, например `"All Files\0*.*\0\0"`, то если написать

```
std::string filter = "All Files\0*.*\0\0";
```

То в `filter` окажутся только символы до первого `\0`, а именно `"All Files"`.

Вы можете добавить шаблонную перегрузку `openFileDialog`, которая работала бы со строковыми литералами:

```
template<int N>
std::string openFileDialog(const char(&filter)[N]) {
  std::string filter_str(filter, filter + N);
  return openFileDialog(filter_str);
}
```

Comment: ну точно, так и вызываю! спс просветил!

Comment: Один нолик не лишний? Си же сам добавит ещё ноль в конец строки, а значит их станет 3.

Comment: Да, насколько я помню, завершение строки должно обозначаться двумя нулями - первый - просто конец секции, второй - что следующей нет. Но ведь в варианте с двумя явно прописанными нулями, их фактически получается три. Или я что-то не учёл?

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` использовать можно, главное его правильно инициализировать. Исходя из описания члена `lpstrFilter` структуры [`OPENFILENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A buffer containing pairs of null-terminated filter strings. The last
>   string in the buffer must be terminated by two NULL characters.

Буфер содержит пары нуль-терминированных строк, а последняя строка должна содержать два таких нуля.

[Конструктор](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) `std::string`, принимающий аргумент типа `const char*` (а именно к этом типу приводится строковый литерал при вызове) инициализирует объект исходя из того, что ему передана обычная нуль-терминированная строка, т.е. символы после первого `NULL` игнорируются. Чтобы поместить в `std::string` нулевые символы можно воспрользоваться другой версией конструктора, который помимо `const char*` принимает также и размер. Т.о. вариант с `std::string` будет работать, если вызывать его например так:

```
openFileDialog(std::string("All Files\0*.*\0\0", sizeof("All Files\0*.*\0\0"));
```

Или с выносом именованного строкового литерала:

```
const char filter[] = "All Files\0*.*\0\0";
openFileDialog(std::string(filter, sizeof(filter));
```

При этом, хочу заметить, что управляющая последовательность, начинающаяся с `\0` интерпретируется как восьмеричное число. Т.е. во избежании недоразумений лучше вместо одного нуля использовать три (максимальное кол-во символов, разрешенное для восьмеричного числа в управляющей последовательности) `\000`. В Вашем конкретном случае это не важно, т.к. `*` не является восьмеричной цифрой, но если бы Вы написали например `"All Files\012*.*\0\0"` для файлов по маске `12*.*` это породило бы ошибку. Надо писать `"All Files\00012*.*\0\0"`.

Ещё одно замечание про передачу `std::string` по значению. Правильнее в данном случае использовать такую сигнатуру:

```
openFileDialog(const std::string& filter);
```

Comment: спасибо очень познавательно - но я все же остановился на обычном "char*", ибо объективно прочитав и изучив все ответы, проблем намного меньше, чем если использовать "string"

Comment: @Duracell в данном случае из-за специфики `winapi` лучше действительно оставить `char*`, не забывая, тем не менее, о правилах формирования escape-последовательностей.